# Is there any option to check the status of accessibility permission in macOS (granted to the app or not) using electron

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder

I am new to electron and I use the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/iohook to get the key strokes pressed by the user. It requires permission of accessibility in system preferences. Is there any possible way to check that is the permission is granted or not for my electron application.Kindly help me to solve this problem and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exact problem. You can programatically prompt the user to enable accessibility with `systemPreferences.isTrustedAccessibilityClient(true)`

If you pass in true it opens the system prompt, if you omit true/add false it returns a boolean as to whether or not the app has accessibility permissions.

API: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/system-preferences#systempreferencesistrustedaccessibilityclientprompt-macos